# How to help my pre-teen who is getting into trouble at school?

Tags: behavior, school, pre-teen, profanity

My daughter has just received a three day suspension from school. She is in seventh grade and this year has gotten progressively worse as time has gone on.

I know that contributing factors are that she is an only child who is desperate to make friends at almost any cost. She resists every effort her mother and I make to get her to socialize with kids in our church congregation and neighborhood. So the only "friends" she has is this clique of "popular" girls in her grade.

She was bullied very badly in fourth grade so we homeschooled in fifth grade, but she begged to go back to school in sixth grade which, despite some early issues interacting with her peers, seemed to end pretty well.

This past week everything came to a head when we learned that she had gotten a hold of another girl's account information, logged in as them and proceeded (with friends) to send out sexually explicit messages. Today we found out that she had compiled a list of accounts of different people. That coupled with the language that her principal is reporting our daughter and her friends used has apparently led to her suspension.

Now I'm back to "do we homeschool again?". She's already in therapy. We've taken away all privileges such as TV, phone, computer access. I'm really not sure where we go from here. She's our oldest and neither of us ever rebelled this way.

Comment: Why is she in therapy already, and with whom (e.g. adolescent psychologist/family therapist/other?) Are you also in counseling (e.g. family therapy or individual/couples counseling)? What has her therapist said about all this? Did your daughter have any traumatic events in the past year (divorce/separation/bullying/other)? How did she get a old of the account info of others? What has your daughter said about why she did all this? Does she care about loss of privileges? Is she banned from associating with those girls from now on? As you can see, we need more info before answers can be given.

Comment: Just FYI, this is not rebellion. This is an intent to actively harm another person, which is different. I feel your pain and confusion. Please edit so someone can post a helpful answer; we're here to help, not judge, and we want to do that. We just need more information, and a specific question - reflecting your most pressing concern - is welcome as well.